# Answer Text Field Blocks Flagging Modal on Downvoted/Greyed out Answers

Tags: bug, flags

I went to flag [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220243/can-you-reset-the-counter-of-a-for-each-loop/29220342#29220342) for being "not an answer" and saw that the answer text field was blocking the flag modal:

[image: bug]

The flagging modal for normal answers displays properly:

[image: correct]

Has anyone seen this before?  Is it a known bug?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251757/flag-dialogs-for-grayed-out-posts-are-also-grayed-out/251858#251858

Comment: Ah, should have known to check meta SE first.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem. That's one of the annoyances of having two metas.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Actually, there are about [137 metas](http://stackexchange.com/)!

Comment: I don't understand why mine was marked as a duplicate when http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288840/flag-window-is-semi-transparent-for-downvoted-answers was posted after this post.  Shouldn't the newer post be marked as a dupe?

Comment: @JAL The other one had an answer and this one didn't. Duplicates don't always have to be chronological.