# Flag window is semi-transparent for downvoted answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, downvotes, design

On an answer with 3 or more downvotes, the `flag` window is semi-transparent, like the answer, which makes the flag options hard to read and select:

[image: Semi-transparent flag window]

The problem is also visible with the `share` window (which also seems to appear below "Your Answer"):

[image: Semi-transparent share window]

Steps to reproduce:

- [Find a bad answer, with score <= -3](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A..-3+is%3Aa)
- Click the `flag` link below the answer

My browser is Firefox 36.0.4.

Comment: Link for people searching: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+score%3A-10..-3

Comment: Same for Chrome 41.0.2272.101 on Windows.

Comment: It makes sense that anything within the post element is dimmed, but I agree that this should change. Those dialog boxes should never be dimmed.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288575/answer-text-field-blocks-flagging-modal-on-downvoted-greyed-out-answers MSE post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251757/flag-dialogs-for-grayed-out-posts-are-also-grayed-out/251858#251858

Comment: Thanks @Kendra, I was not able to find anything related to the issue on MSE.

Comment: And this is why the `opacity` property sucks.

Comment: OH wow, didn't realize `opacity` was being used...

Comment: @Kendra Not just related, those are the same exact issue. I'm voting to close the other MSO post as a duplicate of this one (even though it was asked earlier).

Comment: Also repro on Chrome and Windows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have pushed a fix for this to dev. It will be on live after our next build. Thank you those who suggested solutions.

Comment: ETA when the next build arrives? (hours? tomorrow? :))

Comment: Is this a fix for the [network-wide request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251855/202832)?

Comment: I'm curious how you solved this. ETA is nice to know indeed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard it should happened within the next 24 hours. More likely in 12 hours.

Comment: @Mooseman yes it will be fixed network wide.

Comment: @BramVanroy should happen within 24 hours. The fix was, instead of setting .5 opacity on .downvoted-answers div, I limited the opacity to its .post-text, .post-signature, .votecell, .comments divs only. So this way it doesn't affect the popup div.

Comment: Not the most elegant solution, but I suppose it does the job. ;-)

Comment: @BramVanroy Ideally it'd be nice if the popup html isn't contained in this. It's something I may still talk to our devs about. But for now, the CSS fix is the easiest and fastest to do.

Comment: @Jin Does this fix include the `z-index`?

Comment: @Mooseman yes it should.

Comment: Can you also mark [these](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251855/234299) [two](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251757/234299) MSE posts as status-complete?

Comment: The problem still persists for the flag dialog on comments to downvoted answers. I guess the same treatment using an even messier collection of selectors should fix it.

Comment: The issue continues.

Comment: Still an issue...

Answer (score 15):

Either the modal needs to be appended to a different element, or the css opacity needs to only target the votecell and the post-text elements.

You can see the css change in action with this simple javascript

```
$('.downvoted-answer').css('opacity',1).find('.votecell, .post-text').css('opacity',0.5);
```

[image]

Comment: Surprise, surprise...

Comment: It must be easy for the developers to fix bugs on a site full of programmers since the people reporting the bugs also fix them!

Comment: @NobodyNada I know you're joking, but verifying that a change fixes a bug is not enough. It also needs to be verified that a change is correct, and introduces no other bugs. That's hard. The approach in this answer does introduce another bug, visible in the screenshot: it doesn't set the opacity of the comments.

Comment: @hvd - Isn't that the designed behavior? It could have easily been made to do that if that was the way that the opacity originally operated.

Comment: Also, do note this answer only highlights a way to see the fix, not a suggestion on how to actually implement a patch. This is because the stylesheets SE uses have larger implications than single situations at times, and I wanted to only show the css selection option for fixing this, not necessarily what their edited css style definitions would be as that may have other ramifications I cannot test for at the moment.

Comment: @TravisJ I'm pretty sure the fact that the opacity is currently applied to both the post and the comments is intentional. It looks very distracting when the comments are in black. Anyway, the point of my comment is that contrary to what NobodyNada jokingly suggests, StackOverflow cannot simply copy and paste from your answer to their CSS. I'm sorry if it came across as anything more than that, that wasn't my intention, I certainly am not asking you to edit your answer so that SO can. :)

Comment: This _is_ a good lesson, though.

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to Travis' answer, I've got a suggestion that isn't a convenient way to approach this sort of thing, but I think it's worth considering.

### EDIT 29 March, 2015.

Following up on my old answer, I figured there ought to be a better way to fallback gracefully for older browsers. The first thing that I thought of was: detect browser support for `pointer-events` and then adjust some CSS accordingly. However, I found that it can be done a lot easier with some z-index fun.

The idea is, again, to add an overlay to the downvoted answer with a pseudo element `:after`. With the `pointer-events: none;` property, clicks will fall through that overlay so users will still be able to select text or click the Flag, Edit and Share buttons. However, [this property isn't supported in older IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) and so users won't be able to click these buttons in such browsers. The solution utilises the simple yet efficient power of z-index. Simply position the div that contains those buttons (`.post-menu`) relatively, and add a z-index that's higher than the z-index of the overlay. Ta-da, now everyone can click those buttons.

See the [CodePen here](http://codepen.io/BramVanroy/pen/gbEomV), or the [fullscreen demo here](http://codepen.io/BramVanroy/full/gbEomV/).

**Compiled CSS**

```
.downvoted-answer {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
}
.downvoted-answer:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  pointer-events: none;
}
.downvoted-answer .post-menu {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

**Upside**

- Fixes the issue
- Cross-browser, yay
- Subsequent problems are easy to fix (see "Downside")
- Doesn't require JavaScript
- Adding IE8 support isn't hard, if you really want to. Replace RGBA by the opacity trick mentioned below

**Downside**

- As we position our `.post-menu` relatively, and the pop-up is inside that div, you'll need to adjust the way in which the pop-up's position is determined. (Absolute positioning inside a relatively positioned element and all that.)
- You might need to add a z-index to the pop-up

---

### Old answer.

**Upside**

- Doesn't require JavaScript
- Fixes the problem

**Downside**
 - Doesn't work well in all browsers (see below)

```
.downvoted-answer {
  position: relative;
  /* opacity: 1; */
}
.downvoted-answer:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Basically what you do is creating an overlay with a pseudo-element, and let pointer events "fall through" by setting its `pointer-events` property to `none`. Unfortunately [this isn't widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events), though IE 11 supports it. (It's something.) Also consider that even though IE 8 supports `:after`, it doesn't support [RGBA](http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba). A better approach, then, might be to use (a form of) opacity, like so.

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
opacity: 0.5;
background: white;
```

I do wonder, though, why don't you use one pop-up per page? Now each answer has its own pop-up div, but why don't you simply have one pop-up element at the bottom of the DOM which you only fill with the relevant content upon click?

Comment: The site barely works correctly in IE8 anyway.

Comment: @BoltClock Considering that, I nonetheless added an improved answer which *is* cross-browser.