# "Vote down requires 125 reputation" on answers with -7 votes or less behind the code snippet

Tags: bug, downvotes, design

The "Vote down requires 125 reputation" message appears behind a code snippet on this faded answer, and thus I'm unable to close it.

[image: Vote Down Bug]

Comment: May be to prevent down voting from getting out of control.

Comment: @Carcigenicate It always requires 125 rep. I believe this post is about the bad z-ordering.

Comment: Maybe a side-effect of the fix for this problem? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288840/flag-window-is-semi-transparent-for-downvoted-answers

Comment: If you write decent answers to two or three questions, this will stop being your problem :-P

Comment: @dfeuer: I suggest you read the question again. The rep requirement isn't the problem.

Comment: "...on answers with -7 votes...". I suggest changing that into "...grayed-out answers..." or "...answers with -3 or less score" as all answers which have a score of -3 or less are grayed-out and they also face this issue.

Comment: @Carcigenicate It's already out of control. ;)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If the stacking issue is fixed, it's still hard to read:

[image: Example with corrected stacking]

It seems that it would be better to simply target the individual elements in some way:

```
.downvoted-answer .post-text,
.downvoted-answer .post-signature,
.downvoted-answer .vote-up-off,
.downvoted-answer .vote-down-off,
.downvoted-answer .vote-count-post,
.downvoted-answer .comments {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

This fixes the stacking issue, allowing users to close the message, and makes the message easier to read:

[image: Example with corrected stacking and full opacity]

Comment: Surely there should be a way to not have to enumerate every class inside `downvoted-answer`.

Comment: `.downvoted-answer *:not(.message)` could work... But that `*` selector... Yikes.

Comment: @Cerbrus Shouldn't that be `.downvoted-answer > *:not(.message)`? Otherwise you get opacity over opacity at increasing depth.

Comment: You're right @DavidMulder

Comment: @Cerbrus The * selector is not that bad.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2951997/525478

Comment: StackOverflow has the best user base ever, since the users can solve their programming problems ;)

Comment: Thats the goal of Joel, he probably uses all of you as a QA team.