# The flag dialog for a comment on a downvoted answer is transparent

Tags: bug, flags, design

When I flag a comment on a downvoted answer, the flag dialog is semi-transparent, which makes it hard to use.

> [image: Flag dialog box is transparent]

Steps to reproduce:

- [Find a downvoted answer with score <= 3](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A..-3+is%3Aa) and at leat one comment. (There seems to be no search operator for number of comments ?)
- Attempt to flag one of its comments.

Related to [Flag window is semi-transparent for downvoted answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288840/flag-window-is-semi-transparent-for-downvoted-answers) .

---

Since this seems to affect multiple things, why not **fix** this and all related problems by making the flag dialog **not** a child of the answer, instead of the current workarounds ?

Comment: Do we really need a new report for each and every modal dialog that's a child of -3 answer? There are plenty more modals out there for users to discover being affected by this issue to post about. Let's all do that and create more work for the developers who then have to [status-completed] every last one of these.

Comment: There's also plenty of these bugreports on the over-meta...

Comment: Hesitantly voted to reopen as this issue [reportedly still exists](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3479820#3479820) while the issue it was originally marked as a duplicate of was fixed.