# Odd visual effects when flagging comments

Tags: feature-request, bug, comments, comment-flags

When you click on a flag icon, the popup is appended next to it. For a very short time, it causes a visual bug, because the width of `.comment-flag`'s parent `<td>` is 17 pixel by default (before you click on the icon), but the ajax-loading image is 18 pixel wide and has 3-3px padding.

[image]
[image]

It'd be better to append the popup to `<body>`. That would also solve [another](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289033/the-flag-dialog-for-a-comment-on-a-downvoted-answer-is-transparent) bug.

---

When you click on the icon fast twice, you'll see an error message:

> You may only attempt to flag this comment every 3 seconds.

Instead of this message, if you click on the same icon, the site shouldn't try to display exactly the same popup, that's useless, and you save 1 ajax request.

Comment: Hm, should I split it into 2 questions?

Comment: Are you sure the "another bug" is still current? If there is a "visual" problem, including an image of it will help in your question. Put a freehand red circle around the actual issue(s) you see.

Comment: @BillWoodger Edited the question, that might explain the bug if you can't see.

Comment: The "another bug" that you link to has been "solved" by using the normal text for low-score answers when the mouse is within the post. Are you saying your suggestion would cure the interesting effect when you move the mouse off the answer with the flag box still open. It's hardly a biggie. I'd like to see images of your "visual bug". Even with your extended question, I can't see the problem, perhaps because I don't know what to look for. This may account for your downvotes. It certainly does account for at least one now.

Comment: @BillWoodger http://i.stack.imgur.com/dXFKI.png

Comment: OK, can you try to make the image a lot smaller please, because at the moment I can still see it. Please add a more resonably-sized image *to your question*, and highlight (freehand circle in red) what you think the issue(s) is/are. I don't see what is in your tiny image when I flag a comment.

Comment: @BillWoodger http://i.stack.imgur.com/CQhRj.png

Comment: Can reproduce. It shifts the entire comment section to the right, then normalizes back to the former layout. This is visible for maybe 500ms.

Comment: I bet every comment on this question has been flagged as least once :D

Comment: @YAK dunno you, but I *flajjed* the comments ;)

Comment: This is why you have to be careful when designing a website used by programmers - we'll catch everything.

Comment: The image contains no freehand red circles.  How am I supposed to understand what is going on?

Comment: @ShotgunNinja Haha, yep. After reading over this post, my first thought was "only on StackOverflow would you find a bug report this detailed (complete with recommendations on how to fix it) about such a small issue".

Comment: @Yakk http://i.imgur.com/pXxSmtu.png The issue is within the circles. Can you see it?

Comment: @ShotgunNinja Yes, but you have to admit that it's cool to see bug reports that, rather than complaining about a problem, say, "Here's a problem, and here's a fix for that problem."

Comment: @Yakk Beautiful, just beautiful.