# Downvoted question/answers' comments fades incorrectly

Tags: discussion, bug

*Note: This is **not the same** as [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289033/the-flag-dialog-for-a-comment-on-a-downvoted-answer-is-transparent) (The flag dialog for a comment on a downvoted answer is transparent), however it may be related.*

I was browsing through the Hot Meta Posts, where I saw quite a controversial answer with quite a few downvotes. I noticed that the mouse-over animation for the answer and its comments are different, with one fading in/out much more drastically. In addition, the numbers representing votes for the answer's comments are not properly faded out.

Here's a GIF:
[image]

Comment: They have this style `ul.comments-list .comment-text, ul.comments-list .comment-actions { transition: background-color linear 2s; }` which should be changed to `transition: background-color linear 2s, opacity .5s;`

Comment: What is "incorrect" here? Both the answer and the comments fade, to the same degree, when they are out of focus.