# Comment flag window for transparent answer hidden behind new answer box

Tags: bug, flags, design

I don't know if this is directly related to the [transparent flagging window issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288840/flag-window-is-semi-transparent-for-downvoted-answers), but this seems to be a bit different.  The window will only show up entirely by hovering the mouse over the area not covered by the new answer box.  Clicking in the overlapped area will cause the window to disappear.

[Link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26610312/1950231)

- OS: Windows 7
- Browser: Chrome 45.0.2454.85

Steps to reproduce:

- Click on the comment flag icon. The flagging dialog should appear over the answer box.
  Otherwise, scroll down a bit and try again.
- Move your mouse outside the downvoted answer. You should get the below screenshot.

[image]

(I'll refrain from flagging this comment so that this issue can be tested by others.)

Comment: It's just you.  Name your browser and version number, mention add-ins.

Comment: @HansPassant: Done.  My only add-in was ABP, but it's disabled for the site.

Comment: Same problem here, same version of Chrome, Windows 10.

Comment: Chrome v44 on Fedora 22 and I don't see this issue.

Comment: Reproduced on Firefox 40.0.3

Comment: Can't reproduce this with Chromium 45.0 on Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Reproduced in Chromium 44 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 6):

This problem is caused by the `opacity: .5` which is applied to the entire comment div through `.downvoted-answer .comments`. The flag window is also affected by its grandparents opacity and this messes with the z-layers.

The easy fix is to apply any opacity changes to the individual comment sections instead:

```
.downvoted-answer .post-text,
.downvoted-answer .post-signature,
.downvoted-answer .comment-text,
.downvoted-answer .comment-score,
.downvoted-answer .comment-up-on,
.downvoted-answer .vote>*
```

Fixed:

[image: Fixed]

Hopefully this is the last problem that the opacity change causes.