# Recent Change to Transparent Overlay of Downvoted Answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This is related to [**Flag window is semi-transparent for downvoted answers**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288840/flag-window-is-semi-transparent-for-downvoted-answers) but not related to the flag.

Within the last 2 days (could have been today), on Firefox answers with 3 or so downvotes are covered with a heavy white-transparent overlay when the mouse leaves the answer. The overlay seems to become heavier the farther the mouse gets from answer making is somewhat animated. I don't know if the 'animation' of the overlay was the change or what caused it to become much more visible. This seems much-much heavier an overlay as I've never noticed it in the past and nothing has changed in my browser for a month.

[image]

Was there a change (in either the weight of the overlay or the animation of it) and can it be toned down a bit?

The idea is sound, but it becomes visually distracting to have part of the screen blur-away as the mouse distance from it increases -- enough that it took time to figure out if there is a problem with my display, my browser, or just another inane web antic.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the fading has nothing to do with how far the cursor is the from the answer. It's either faded or not (with a short transition period upon crossing the edge of the answer).

Comment: Maybe it's just due to me reading on a 1440x900 screen and not having that far to move up/down, but when I move the cursor just above the bad answer, there is definitely a gradient to the fade over an inch or so of screen space. Could be the way FF(esr) handles the overlay as well. Thanks for the input.